# Android - ConcurrentModificationException - Read and remove in different threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, hashmap, gson

I'm having problems with ConcurrentModificationException occuring when working with threads and HashMaps. And would like some ideas how to read and change a HashMap simultaniously, if possible. Or is the best solution just to queue the threads after each other?

Example of the HashMap:

```
protected final ConcurrentHashMap<Long, DataItem> dataItemQueue = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, RegisterStorageLocationQueueItem>();
```

What the thread does (basically):

```
Job job = new Job(var1, var2, dataItemQueue);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("job", new Gson().toJson(job));
// Saving/sending the serialized data.
storeItemData();
```

While the thread is running this I process the "Data Items" and remove them from the HashMap when done, one by one. Sometimes I get this Exception which I guess is when removing an item from the HashMap while it is trying to serialize it with Gson. I run the thread to speed up the whole process as the work done in the thread might take 2-4 seconds and I don't want to lock the main thread.

I tried to solve this by using ConcurrenthashMap and cloning the HashMap inside the thread so that it shouldn't lock the Hashmap as shown below. But I haven't found a working solution for it.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Long, DataItem> newDataItemQueue = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, DataItem>();
for (Entry<Long, DataItem> entry : this.dataItemQueue.entrySet()) {
    newDataItemQueue.put(entry.getKey(), new DataItem(entry.getValue()));
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:792)
at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:829)
at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:827)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:206)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:600)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:579)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:534)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:514)
at com.asd.admin.fragments.DataFragment.saveStateData(DataFragmentment.java:825)
```

Comment: Can you share the definition of `Job`? It seems likely it (possibly indirectly) has a `HashMap` member field.

Comment: Job is a class with a least one property that is a HashMap.

Comment: Well if you're interacting with that map across threads that's a problem - `HashMap` is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your stack trace you'll see that a `HashMap` is being concurrently modified while Gson is iterating it (notice the `com.google.gson` calls before `HashMap$EntryIterator.next`.

By the looks of it on line 825 of `DataFragment.java` you're passing an object (`Job`, I assume?) containing a `HashMap` to Gson, but you're concurrently updating that `HashMap` in a separate thread. You probably just need to find where this `HashMap` is being declared inside `Job` and change it to a `ConcurrentHashMap`, which won't throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

You cannot *ever* safely work with `HashMap` or other non-thread-safe objects across multiple threads. Your choices are a) use thread-safe data structures or b) use external synchronization or locking mechanisms to ensure thread-safety.

Answer (score -1):

Use java iterator to avoid concurrent modification exception.

```
Map<Long, DataItem> dataItemQueue  = new HashMap<>();
Iterator iterator = dataItemQueue.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    if( /* your condition goes here */ ){
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: This *only* works if the modification is a removal. If you're instead adding or replacing elements this strategy is insufficient. Additionally even `Iterator.remove()` is not safe if a `HashMap` is being accessed across multiple threads - it might not trigger a CME but it's still likely to cause inconsistent or broken behavior.